# Laravel save data to database with Model SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: php, database, sqlite, laravel

When i try to save to database i keep getting these errors

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 479:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: images.uploader


QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: images.uploader (SQL: insert into "images" ("name", "description", "updated_at", "created_at") values (coat, description test, 2016-12-11 10:34:34, 2016-12-11 10:34:34))
```

The store function in my controller

```
public function store($name)
{
    $image = new Image;
    $image->name = $name;
    $image->description = "description test";

    $image->save();

}
```

the migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('uploader');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('width');
        $table->integer('height');
        $table->decimal('size');
        $table->integer('views')->default(0);
        $table->string('extension');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and my Model

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["name", "description"];
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, ive been stuck on this for way too long.
I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that column `uploader` shouldn't be `NULL`.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: images.uploader
```

Change your migration to

```
$table->string('uploader')->default('');
```

OR

```
$table->string('uploader')->nullable();
```

Alternately, you can use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators), put this in your `Image` model.

```
public function setUploaderAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['uploader'] = (is_null($value) ? '': $value);
}
```

Comment: I see so every column that I don't fill needs to be nullable or have a default  of an empty string
is that right?

Comment: Yup, basically those constraints are there to make sure you have the right data in your database. So if you expect it to be empty, you should state it